# npm ERR! code E404 when installing Expo Tracking Transparency

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

expo install expo-tracking-transparency
Installing 1 other package using npm.

> npm install --save expo-tracking-transparency
> npm ERR! code E404
> npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/expo-tracking-transparency - Not found
> npm ERR! 404
> npm ERR! 404  'expo-tracking-transparency@latest' is not in the npm registry.
> npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
> npm ERR! 404
> npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
> npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm exited with non-zero code: 1

Comment: @AjeetShah according to expo docs it exists 
https://docs.expo.io/versions/v41.0.0/sdk/tracking-transparency/